# Redmine 3.3.0 (ruby on rails 4.2.6) stylesheets not generated/included in application.css

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I have installed redmine, managed to get it started but the UI seems to be missing it's css styles. If I follow the link for application[SomeId].css It show me an empty css containing the following message:

```
 /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 */
```

**production.log** seems fine

```
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 9.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/application-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css" for ::1 at 2016-09-16 01:34:36 +0300
Started GET "/assets/application-c2899b9307d416d19b1525a85be8085b93df756e91a5b0ee50ab1333f5ade73a.js" for ::1 at 2016-09-16 01:34:36 +0300
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
```

- **redmine 3.3.0**
- **ruby 2.2.4**
- **rails 4.2.6**
- latest xampp **xampp-win32-7.0.9-1-VC14-installer**

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my blunder was that I didn't run 'Redmine' at all in development mode. As I understand until now, the ruby on rails asset pipeline wasn't fired up to generate the concatenated `application.css`. All I had to do was to run the server once in development mode.

```
rake assets:precompile
rails server -e development
```

Also found some useful info in this answer: [Rails assets not precompiling, css looks different in production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626661/1903781) and [Rails 4: assets not loading in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production)

This is my first encounter with RoR and I blindly followed an install tutorial for 'Redmine' that didn't include the compile step.

**Edit**
The issue returned, actually it wasn't even fixed properly. Had to solve some issues with `mysql2` adapter and login credentials in order to properly populate the database. After that I tried a lot of things until finally arriving to this steps list:

Added in **environments/production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 
config.assets.digest = true
```

- Kill the server
- Clear out tmp/cache/assets
- Delete public/assets
- Run rake assets:precompile
- Start up the server rails s -e production
- Reloading the page

Run in cmd:

```
set RAILS_ENV=production
rake generate_secret_token

set RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate

set RAILS_ENV=production
rake redmine:load_default_data

set RAILS_ENV=production
rake tmp:cache:clear

set RAILS_ENV=production
rake assets:precompile

set RAILS_ENV=production
rails server -e development
```

If I visited the page and opened up web inspector, when I clicked the elink for `application.css` I still got the empty .css

Eventually I figured out that instead that the gziped version had a size of 1kb which was intriguing. I deleted it and VOILA, it worked. Basically I solved my issue, but I still don't know why the gzip is generated with the empty css.